# Set up a UIImageView for a Popup

Tags: swift, uiimageview, popup, uiimage

This function that gets called calls a view controller called PopupViewController fill the screen:

```
func callSavedPopup() {
    let popupViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupViewController") as! PopupViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popupViewController)
    popupViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    popupViewController.userChoiceImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "CheckMark.png"))

    popupViewController.userChoiceLabel.text = "Congrats! Your run was saved!"
    self.view.addSubview(popupViewController.view)
    popupViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

In the PopupViewController.swift, there is an outlet for the image:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userChoiceImage: UIImageView!
```

How do I go making the userChoiceImage hold the image with the title "CheckMark.png" from the top function. They are in two different classes

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure the spelling of your filename (CheckMark.png) is correct! :-)

2.) Make sure the outlet is not hidden by default on the storyboard.

3.) Make sure your image is hooked up correctly to the outlet (ctrl + dragging)

4.) Instead of doing:

```
 popupViewController.userChoiceImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "CheckMark.png"))
```

try the following:

```
popupViewController.userChoiceImage.image = UIImage(named: "CheckMark.png")
```

that way you keep your ImageView size, positioning, etc.